# PHP If Post Value is less than or greater than

Tags: php, ajax, if-statement, error-handling

I have a php booking form which checks to make sure that information has been entered in the boxes before its submitted:

I use the following to check to make sure group has a value in it.

```
if(!isset($_POST['group']) || trim($_POST['group']) == '')
{
    $error.= "Group Size is required<br/>";
}
```

How can I use an IF statement too check that the value in group is greater than 39 but less than 400?

Comment: easy; use `strlen()` - btw; `trim($_POST['group']) == '')` why trim that? Question's a tad unclear also.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($_POST['group']) && is_numeric($_POST['group']))
{
    if($_POST['group'] < 400 && $_POST['group'] > 39)
    {
        //here you go
    }
}
```

The empty also checks for existence. You should always check the type of the values youre getting, not only if empty - type casting gets done by php for you

Other answer is wrong btw, question is greater than 39, not greater or equal 39

Comment: https://3v4l.org/4YATq 
Really don't understand what you are expecting...

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
if(strlen(trim($_POST['code'])) >= 39 && strlen(trim($_POST['code'])) < 400)
```

Comment: this looks for greater than 39 but not less than 401?